# image in layout is different from image loaded in emulator

Tags: android

My problem is as follows:

I have a layout called layoutscreen.xml . On this layout I have various buttons. To add a resource I went to imagebutton which took me to the resource screen and then added a particular image in this case basic.png. I got this off my hard drive and I noticed the image had not rescaled properly. I then went too drawable-hdpi and replaced basic.png that had been shrunk with a new copy off my hard drive.

Therefore showing the full sized image. I then went to background and changed it to the resource of the new image. It displayed fine. The problem was when I ran the emulator the old basic.png was still there after the replacement.

What is the best practice to add an image to a button?

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way is to create a folder called drawable in res folder. And when using images refer to them inside the xml syntax for example  `android:background="@drawable/user"`. You would then add this syntax within a button xml syntax for example. Here is an exammple of the background property used within a button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/profile_btn"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:background="@drawable/user" />
```